# Sqlite3 error when non-command typed in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04, python-bindings

When you typed gibberish input in terminal this always happen:

```bash
some@user:~/home/myfolder$ a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_trace
```

Does anyone know why this is happening on Ubuntu 20.04?

I saw this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1397568/sqlite3-error-in-ubuntu20-04) and it is same problem but with no answer

Comment: Seems like there's a tool written in Python which should help you find not yet installed packages you might need based on what commands you tried to run, but the tool is not properly installed.

Comment: It not works even when I try to apt-get update. it will crash with same error somewhere in middle of updating. So it is happening also with know commands

Comment: A wild guess: `sudo apt install --reinstall command-not-found libpython3.8-stdlib`?

Comment: I don't think I get you @Biffen